# elastic-operator (eck) restarts a lot

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

I currently have elastic-operator 1.4.0 version running on an AKS cluster. It has a high restarting count of 50 in 95 days for a prod env. Is this normal behavior for this eck operator or is it related to needing an upgrade to the latest version? A common error seen in the logs is:
error retrieving resource lock elastic/elastic-operator-leader: Get "https://{ip}/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace_name}/configmaps/elastic-operator-leader?timeout=1m0s": net/http: TLS handshake timeout